# Why does a JavaScript file named 'index.js' not work in Django templates?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, django

I am working on a Django project and my JavaScript file was not loading on the HTML template. After a lot of tinkering, what finally got the file to load was changing its name from 'index.js' to 'homepage.js' but I could have changed it to anything. I wanted to keep the file consistent with the HTML and CSS files that are named 'index.html' and 'index.css'.

Why is this the case that 'index.js' failed to load? It doesn't seem like file name should matter. I am mainly curious but hopefully this could help others.

Comment: Probably a server configured issue.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that where you are extending the template from is correctly configured. You may be requiring `homepage.js` from a different template. I'd recommend having a CSS block that the templates can override when extending from the main template.

`main.html`

```
<html>
  <head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/styles/main.css" />
    {% block css_block %}{% endblock %}

    <script src="/static/js/main.js"></script>
    {% block js_block %}{% endblock %}

  </head>
  <body>
    {% block body_block %}{% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>
```

`template.html`

```
{% extends 'main.html' %}

{% block css_block %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/styles/resource/index.css" />
{% endblock %}

{% block body_block %}
  ...
{% endblock %}
```

Writing anything in a block after extending **overrides that block in the parent template**. It doesn't concatenate. Put any CSS/JS that you want on multiple pages in `main.html`, and the single page assets in their respective templates, in their respective blocks.

If you're trying to carry a block up two levels of `extends`, you must make sure that block is present (it can be empty) in the intermediate template.